# How to re-render a Widget based on another widget using riverpod in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-state, flutter-riverpod

I want to know how can I refresh a table data (which is fetched from an API using a future provider) and re-render the table widget based on dropdown value change.

Following is the Repo file with providers:

```
import 'package:ct_analyst_app/src/features/dashboard/domain/dashboard_data.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../../authentication/application/auth_local_service.dart';

abstract class IDashboardRepository {
  Future<void> fetchDashboard(String name);
  Future<void> fetchNames();
}

final clientProvider = Provider.family((ref, token) => Dio(BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: "http://${dotenv.env['IP']}/excel/",
    headers: {"authorization": token})));

class DashboardRepository implements IDashboardRepository {
  DashboardRepository(this.read);

  final Reader read;

  DashboardData? _data;
  DashboardData? get dashboardData => _data;

  List<dynamic>? _names;
  List<dynamic>? get names => _names;

  @override
  Future<DashboardData?> fetchDashboard(String name) async {
    final token = await read(authServiceProvider).getToken();

    final response = await read(clientProvider(token))
        .get('/getData', queryParameters: {"name": name});

    _data = DashboardData.fromJson(response.data);
    print(name);
    return _data;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> fetchNames() async {
    final token = await read(authServiceProvider).getToken();
    final response = await read(clientProvider(token)).get('/analystNames');

    _names = response.data["names"];
  }
}

final dashboardRepositoryProvider =
    Provider((ref) => DashboardRepository(ref.read));

final fetchDashboardData = FutureProvider.family<void, String>((ref, name) {
  final repoProvider = ref.watch(dashboardRepositoryProvider);
  return repoProvider.fetchDashboard(name);
});

final fetchAnalystNames = FutureProvider((ref) {
  final repoProvider = ref.watch(dashboardRepositoryProvider);
  return repoProvider.fetchNames();
});
```

I have tried to refresh the future provider in the dropdown onChange and it does fetch the new table data from the API. However, the widget which renders the data in the table is not getting re-rendered when the refresh is called.

Done as following:

```
 onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        ref.read(dropItemProvider.notifier).state = newValue as String;
        ref.refresh(fetchDashboardData(newValue));
        setState(() {
          widget.value = newValue;
        });
      },
```

I am using ref.watch on the data, still it does not re-render the widget if the data is changed.

```
class TableGenerator extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TableGenerator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final data = ref.watch(dashboardRepositoryProvider);

    return data.dashboardData != null
        ? SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const FixedColumnWidget(data: [
                  "one",
                  "two",
                  "three",
                  "four",
                  "fifth",
                ]),
                ScrollableColumnWidget(
                    data: data.dashboardData as DashboardData)
              ],
            ))
        : const CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```

Am I missing something or how should I approach this problem? like different providers or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: I 100% agree with the answer given below. Also you shouldn't need to call `setState` in the `onChanged` callback, and you shouldn't need to add variables like `_data`, `dashboardData`, `_names`, `names` in the repository.

Comment: @bizz84 , I am using the same approach when authenticating the app. Like I have a  variable named user which stores the user data when logged in. Do I have to refactor that too? 
 https://github.com/dk5761/ct_analyst_app/blob/main/lib/src/features/authentication/data/auth_repository.dart

I have used this in auth as in many sample applications for the firebase auth we have a currentUser variable. Though in my case it is not an firebase backend, I thought I could work with the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Widget is watching `dashboardRepositoryProvider`, which doesn't update after the `ref.refresh` call.

There's two things to consider:

1. `dashboardRepository` should just expose your repo / services, and instead it is used to observe actual data. This is not affecting your app *directly*, but it is part of the problem imho. I'd expect your Widget to observe a `FutureProvider` that exposes (and caches, etc.) the data by calling the methods inside your repository;
2. Then, let's analyze why your Widget isn't updating: `dashboardRepository` isn't depending, i.e. performing a `watch`, on the Provider you're refreshing, which is `fetchDashboardData`, nor it is depending on `dropItemProvider` (I am specifying this since your `onChanged` callback updates / refreshes two different Providers).

I think your should refactor your code so that it will expose actual data from a `FutureProvider` which exploits your repositories and can be simply refreshed similarly as what you already are doing.

Quick `FutureProvider` example:

```dart
// WARNING: PSEUDOCODE

final myDataProvider = FutureProvider<MyClass>((ref) {
  final repo = ref.watch(myRepo);

  final response = repo.getSomeData(...);
  // TODO: add error handling, debouncing, cancel tokens, etc.

  return MyClass.fromJson(response.data);  // e.g.
});
```

Quick usage:

```dart
// WARNING: PSEUDOCODE

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final myData = ref.watch(myDataProvider);

  return ElevatedButton(
    onTap: () {
      ref.invalidate(myDataProvider);
    },
    child: Text("Click me to refresh me (data: $myData)"),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation. I would refactor the code as you suggested and test it.

Comment: thanks for the help. I got to know we cannot refresh a ".family" provider. Which was also, the part of the issue.

Comment: This sounds new to me; could you point me towards the documentation or reference where it says you cannot refersh a `.family` Provider?

Comment: It was an issue raised in Riverpod git. 
Following is the link for the issue: https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/879

Comment: Oh, you mean to refresh the *whole* family. Then it makes sense to use the workaround Remi offered.